# querying for different PFFile objects in the database

Tags: ios, download, parse-platform, pfobject, pffile

We are developing an app in which we are querying for different objects in the database. 
Those objects have a PFFile attached to them. It can be either a video or a photo.

When I get the query response, I have the PFObjects that I want, but not the PFFile content.
I’ve read a lot about this, and I know this is the normal behavior, I know that the PFFiles are stored separately from the PFObject.

In this particular case, I need to get the PFObject along with the PFFile, so, when I show the image or play the video, it is already downloaded and I don’t have to wait for it to download.

I’ve tried adding an “include” to the query, but it gives me an error saying something like “PFFile is not a pointer to another PFObject”.

Is there a way to do this? to have the PFObject and the PFFile downloaded at the same time?

PS: I’m using the lates Parse iOS SDK (v 1.5)

Thanks!

Comment: can u paste the query here for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks Ismail. Here is our query:

var cardQuery = new Parse.Query("Card");
 cardQuery.include("cardUser");
 cardQuery.include("cardQuestion");
        // cardQuery.include("cardFile"); // This is the PFFile, but I can't include it in the query
       cardQuery.find({...});

Comment: Do you do synchronous or asynchronous calls to Parse? In the latter case, just download the PFFile in the completion block of the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method, and afterwards call back to your mainthread.